# How to set a dynamic variable as global variable in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, global-variables, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to set a global variable with  the value build_{BUILD_NUMBER}(jenkins global variable), which is dynamic. How can I set this in jenkins global properties?
How can it recognize the build number I'm referring to ?

Comment: i think the top level variables are global variables. you may also use an environment variable.

Comment: okay, but how can i pass the global variable to an environment variable  ?

Answer (score 1):

using a declarative pipeline, you can set an environment variable based on this other environment variable (BUILD_NUMBER) like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  environment {
    MY_BUILD_IDENTIFIER = "build_${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
  }
  stages {
    stage('hot_stage') {
      steps {
        echo "MY_BUILD_IDENTIFIER: ${env.MY_BUILD_IDENTIFIER}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

produces output like this:

```
[Pipeline] echo
MY_BUILD_IDENTIFIER: build_153
```

Comment: Is that MY_BUILD_IDENTIFIER is accessible for other jobs in jenkins without defining it in the jobs?

Comment: definitely not. :) i think you'd need to write a plugin to accomplish that if that's what you're going for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example script, how to alter global environment variables:

```
nodes = Jenkins.instance.globalNodeProperties
nodes.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)

if ( nodes.size() != 1 ) {
  println("error: unexpected number of environment variable containers: ${nodes.size()}, expected: 1")
} else {
  envVars = nodes[0].envVars
  envVars[args[0]] = args[1]
  Jenkins.instance.save()
  println("okay")
}
```

reference:
https://gist.github.com/johnyzed/2af71090419af2b20c5a

Comment: This gives me `java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.util.DescribableList` (Jenkins 2.19)